# Is there a way to have a pop-up generate on the home page once you've been redirected from a form submission on another page?

Tags: php, html

I have a logging application. You click the "Log" button, it takes you to another page with all of the forms etc. After I click "Submit" on this page, it submits to my database and redirects back to the home page. What I want to happen is when I click "Submit", it redirects to home page, and then has a pop-up that says something like "Thanks for the submission!". I've looked through the forums but can't really find anything specific to this application. Thanks.

Comment: Send a parameter with the redirect. On homepage if parameter is set display message.

Comment: ^or use session variable

Comment: ^don't use session variable

Comment: @Dagon, i was being critic. But John Wu explained better in his answer. That was my point as well but he answered so i didn't.

Answer (score 2):

There are a ton of ways to do this.  The general idea is

1. The home page must contain code that displays the "popup," but only under certain conditions (e.g. a flag is passed somehow).  Normal access to the home page should not trigger the condition.
2. The DB submission page must trigger the aforementioned condition when redirecting to the home page.

The "condition" could be as simple as setting a variable in the querystring, e.g. `http://domain.com/home.php?showConfirmation=true`.  The problem with using the querystring is that the user could bookmark it and see the confirmation every time he uses the bookmark.

Another way to set the condition is to set a cookie, session variable, or pass the data via form/post.  All of these have advantages and disadvantages.

You could also do it some fancy way, e.g. perhaps your site needs the general capability of displaying one-time messages.  If the user is registered and authenticated, you'd be able to look up a DB table to see what messages are left to display to the user, and the home page would be coded to automatically display them (marking the DB record so that it doesn't get displayed again).  The DB submission page would add the record for the confirmation message, and in addition you could use this feature for other types of home page messages that you dream up later, e.g. special promotions or new features.  (I don't recommend building features you don't really need).

Answer (score 0):

Send a paramater in the query string.

```
//home-page/?registered=1
```

Or you can set a cookie and check for the cookie if its set.. show the popup and delete it when user clicks on close popup.